# using classes in pygame to create a rectangle?

Tags: python, pygame

The problem is actually with creating rectangles in pygame. Obviously its just `pygame.draw.rect()`, but my issues are when im trying to draw a rectangle within a class, and using `def __init__()`

I've tried to use an attribute in the `__init__` statement to draw the rectangles, but found that comes up with errors. This seems to be the most successful way, but is still not displaying the boxes.

```
class rectangles:

    def __init__(self, command, display, colour, x, y, width, height):
        self.command = command
        self.display = display
        self.colour = colour
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.width = int(width)
        self.height = int(height)

    def rectdraw(self):
        return (self.command, self.display, self.colour, self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

block1 = rectangles(pygame.draw.rect, window, black, 100, 100, 200, 200)
block2 = rectangles(pygame.draw.rect, window, black, 20, 20, 400, 600)
block3 = rectangles(pygame.draw.rect, window, black, 800, 500, 40, 40)    


(block1.rectdraw())
(block2.rectdraw())
(block3.rectdraw())
```

(I have also created the window for pygame as well, just not included it here)

Although the program does not come up with any errors, it will just come up with a blank screen and not display the boxes that I want. This is especially puzzling, and it leads me to think there is something wrong with my classes.

Comment: if anyone knows anything about classes or pygame  i will be really grateful. even just a suggestion helps. Ive been working on this for the longest time, trying to use different methods. -- ill be happy to discuss things ive done, and ideas people have. -- to be honest ive spent too long on this and i really need it off my mind

Comment: im guessing `return (self.command, self.display, self.colour, self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)` should be `return self.command(self.display, self.colour, self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)`

Comment: the more important question is why are you trying to do this, and how does `rectangles` differ from just using `pygame.draw.rect`?

Comment: @dangee1705 OH MY GOD I was that close. I cant believe it. It finally works. Thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: no problem. did that work for you? because if so I can write it as a comment so you can accept this as the answer

Comment: @dangee1705 im trying to this so i can set the x, y, width, and height variables to the same attribute in order to move the display. basically: if the charecter reaches a certain point on a screen, i want all the blocks to move one way, so the charecter looks like hes moving, but its actually the background. instead of having to set all the blocks to move mannually, i wanted to do it like this to save time, incase i add more blocks (which i will) in the future. That probably doesnt make sense, but, overall it will just make my program more effiecient. Thanks again for the help

Comment: and yes that completely worked for me. if you would like to write it as an answer you can, maybe for the future, incase others get stuck or need help. i doubt anyone will have this specifc problem again, but you never know

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have in your code is that where you have written

```
return (self.command, self.display, self.colour, self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

you should have written

```
return self.command(self.display, self.colour, self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

instead